# Decrypt a coldfusion file that was encrypted with cfcompile.bat

Tags: encryption, coldfusion

I would like to decrypt a `.cfm` ColdFusion file that was encrypted with CFCOMPILE.BAT. I have searched the internet for this, but it proved futile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cfcompile](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd0.html) doesn't *encrypt* files. It compiles files into java bytecode. The resulting files can be decompiled into java code, but they can't be converted back into regular CFML code.

Comment: For more details, see Rupesh Kumars (ColdFusion engineering team) [blog post](http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2008/01/encrypted-cfml-templates.html) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks too @Twillen Got a lot from that link you posted

Answer (score -1):

here you go, I haven't used it since 2005 :-)

[cfdecypt](https://www.brainiacmedia.net/cfdecrypt.zip)

Comment: Thanks. Just downloaded the app. How am i able to decrypt with this?

Comment: OK. I'm i to use the method of cfcompile too? Or i just run it on a command line @JamesAMohler

Comment: inbox me the file, and ill decompile it for you. rob@brainiacmedia.net

Comment: OK. Thanks @JamesAMohler I tried using the cmd to run the command (something like this `>C:\Users\WESLEY\Desktop\cfdecrypt\cfdecrypt.exe C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\YSR-uncompiled\pro_sendsms.cfm` but it says file not an ecrypted template.

The was compiled with cfcompile. So, i am not sure if compiling is the same as encrypting. Since it's not taking the file as an encrypted one, which it is.

Comment: @Rob Ok. I have just sent it to your mail